# iPhone 5s - What is the dot between rear camera and the LED flash?

Tags: hardware, iphone

There is a visible dot on the iPhone 5s between the rear camera and the LED flash. What is it for? I imagine it is a sensor of some kind.

I'm concerned because my new iPhone 5s case covers it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a microphone, useful for video recording using the rear camera and for digitally eliminating background noise when you're on a phone or FaceTime call. Source - [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203792).

Apple doesn't have an explicitly stated opinion on whether or not the rear microphone absolutely can't be covered, but in that support article,

> Remove screen protectors, films, or cases that cover the microphone, iSight mic, or iPhone receiver.

is the third recommended step for people experiencing microphone issues.

[image: iPhone diagram]

Comment: Beat me by 9 seconds

Answer (score 1):

That is a microphone. I wouldn't worry about a case covering it too much, as your iPhone 5s has multiple microphones on it. Obviously it would be better if the case didn't cover it, though.